# how to find documents that only contain searched words in `solr`

Tags: solr, phrase

For example, I have a `solr` collection that contains documents with a field called "key_phrase".

I know it is easy to find all documents that contain all the searched words in a search query. (i.e. using `mm`=100% in `edismax`)

However, what I am asking for is how to return documents whose "**key_phrase**" contains only the searched words and nothing else. This "**key_phrase**" is also a multi_valued field.

For example:
Search query:  '**kids soccer gear**'
The query would return the following document whose "**key_phrase**" field contains: "**kids soccer**". 
It would also return a document who have two "**key_phrase**" values such as '**kids gear**' and '**any other word**' since one of them does not contain any words that is not in the search query.

On the other hand, it would not return a document that has '**kids soccer gear for boy**' since this document contains '**boy**', which is not present in the search query.

Comment: What's your question actually???

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you've tried so far. Looks like an AND search on a properly configured field type might be what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can try by indexing the field using the `ShingleFilterFactory`.

e.g.

```
<filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="3" outputUnigrams="true"/>
```

you can refer  here [ShingleFilterFactory](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-ShingleFilter)

```
<analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

If you have the input as

In: `"To be, or what?"`

Tokenizer to Filter: `"To"(1), "be"(2), "or"(3), "what"(4)`

Out: `"To"(1), "To be"(1), "be"(2), "be or"(2), "or"(3), "or what"(3), "what"(4)`